# Issue to use switch

Tags: excel, ssas, dax, olap-cube

```
Amount :=
IF (
    HASONEVALUE ( MeasureType[Type] );
    SWITCH (
        VALUES ( MeasureType[Type] );
        "Actual"; SUM( measure1 );
        "Budget"; SUM( measure2 )
    )
)
```

I got the exact value for `"Actual"; Sum(measure1)` while using cube value function but when I am using `"Budget"; Sum(measure2)` I did not get the exact value.

Can anyone check this code what is the problem ?

Actually, I want to create a measure which will show value according to type as if I am selecting

```
"[Measuretype].[Actual]"; "[Measure].[amount]"= 123

"[Measuretype].[Budget]"; "[Measure].[amount]"= 423
```

Any input is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Regards,

Shilpi

Comment: Before you get an answer, you need to fix your question, you need to indent you code using Ctrl + K

Comment: Please update your Question to be more complete... current situation (includes info about your source data), what the error is, where the error occurs, and what is the desire for your code.  At this point your post is `Unclear`, a grounds for closing.  Note that StackOverflow is a collaborative site for resolving *specific* coding issues.  "DId not get the exact value" could be a list of problems, and more info may be needed.

Comment: Sorry about unclear post actually it is resolved ...